# Cannot link to matlab libmat.so and libmx.so under Eclipse IDE

Tags: linux, c++, shared-library, eclipse, matlab

I am trying to compile **matcreat.cpp** under **Eclipse C++ IDE**. It allows to exchange matlab data with c++ programs. At some point I compile the program :

```
/*
 * matcreat.cpp - MAT-file creation program
 *
 * See the MATLAB External Interfaces/API Guide for compiling information.
 *
 * Calling syntax:
 *
 *   matcreat
 *
 * Create a MAT-file which can be loaded into MATLAB.
 *
 * This program demonstrates the use of the following functions:
 *
 *  matClose
 *  matGetVariable
 *  matOpen
 *  matPutVariable
 *  matPutVariableAsGlobal
 *
 * Copyright 1984-2007 The MathWorks, Inc.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* For strcmp() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* For EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <vector> /* For STL */
#include "mat.h"

#define BUFSIZE 256

int main() {
  MATFile *pmat;
  mxArray *pa1, *pa2, *pa3;
  std::vector<int> myInts;
  myInts.push_back(1);
  myInts.push_back(2);
  printf("Accessing a STL vector: %d\n", myInts[1]);

  double data[9] = { 1.0, 4.0, 7.0, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0 };
  const char *file = "mattest.mat";
  char str[BUFSIZE];
  int status; 

  printf("Creating file %s...\n\n", file);
  pmat = matOpen(file, "w");
  if (pmat == NULL) {
    printf("Error creating file %s\n", file);
    printf("(Do you have write permission in this directory?)\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  pa1 = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(3,3,mxREAL);
  if (pa1 == NULL) {
      printf("%s : Out of memory on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__); 
      printf("Unable to create mxArray.\n");
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  pa2 = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(3,3,mxREAL);
  if (pa2 == NULL) {
      printf("%s : Out of memory on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      printf("Unable to create mxArray.\n");
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  memcpy((void *)(mxGetPr(pa2)), (void *)data, sizeof(data));
  
  pa3 = mxCreateString("MATLAB: the language of technical computing");
  if (pa3 == NULL) {
      printf("%s :  Out of memory on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      printf("Unable to create string mxArray.\n");
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  status = matPutVariable(pmat, "LocalDouble", pa1);
  if (status != 0) {
      printf("%s :  Error using matPutVariable on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }  
  
  status = matPutVariableAsGlobal(pmat, "GlobalDouble", pa2);
  if (status != 0) {
      printf("Error using matPutVariableAsGlobal\n");
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } 
  
  status = matPutVariable(pmat, "LocalString", pa3);
  if (status != 0) {
      printf("%s :  Error using matPutVariable on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } 
  
  /*
   * Ooops! we need to copy data before writing the array.  (Well,
   * ok, this was really intentional.) This demonstrates that
   * matPutVariable will overwrite an existing array in a MAT-file.
   */
  memcpy((void *)(mxGetPr(pa1)), (void *)data, sizeof(data));
  status = matPutVariable(pmat, "LocalDouble", pa1);
  if (status != 0) {
      printf("%s :  Error using matPutVariable on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } 
  
  /* clean up */
  mxDestroyArray(pa1);
  mxDestroyArray(pa2);
  mxDestroyArray(pa3);

  if (matClose(pmat) != 0) {
    printf("Error closing file %s\n",file);
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /*
   * Re-open file and verify its contents with matGetVariable
   */
  pmat = matOpen(file, "r");
  if (pmat == NULL) {
    printf("Error reopening file %s\n", file);
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /*
   * Read in each array we just wrote
   */
  pa1 = matGetVariable(pmat, "LocalDouble");
  if (pa1 == NULL) {
    printf("Error reading existing matrix LocalDouble\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (mxGetNumberOfDimensions(pa1) != 2) {
    printf("Error saving matrix: result does not have two dimensions\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  pa2 = matGetVariable(pmat, "GlobalDouble");
  if (pa2 == NULL) {
    printf("Error reading existing matrix GlobalDouble\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (!(mxIsFromGlobalWS(pa2))) {
    printf("Error saving global matrix: result is not global\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  pa3 = matGetVariable(pmat, "LocalString");
  if (pa3 == NULL) {
    printf("Error reading existing matrix LocalString\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  
  status = mxGetString(pa3, str, sizeof(str));
  if(status != 0) {
      printf("Not enough space. String is truncated.");
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (strcmp(str, "MATLAB: the language of technical computing")) {
    printf("Error saving string: result has incorrect contents\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* clean up before exit */
  mxDestroyArray(pa1);
  mxDestroyArray(pa2);
  mxDestroyArray(pa3);

  if (matClose(pmat) != 0) {
    printf("Error closing file %s\n",file);
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("Done\n");
  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

At some point the program depends on libmat.so and libmx.so Matlab API so I wonder how to link it under Eclipse. Without any link I get

```
18:57:21 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project essai ****
make all 
Building target: essai
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "essai" ./matcreat.o   
/usr/bin/ld : ./matcreat.o : dans la fonction « main » :
/home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:44 : référence indéfinie vers « matOpen_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:51 : référence indéfinie vers « mxCreateDoubleMatrix_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:58 : référence indéfinie vers « mxCreateDoubleMatrix_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:64 : référence indéfinie vers « mxGetPr_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:66 : référence indéfinie vers « mxCreateString_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:73 : référence indéfinie vers « matPutVariable_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:79 : référence indéfinie vers « matPutVariableAsGlobal_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:85 : référence indéfinie vers « matPutVariable_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:96 : référence indéfinie vers « mxGetPr_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:97 : référence indéfinie vers « matPutVariable_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:104 : référence indéfinie vers « mxDestroyArray_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:105 : référence indéfinie vers « mxDestroyArray_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:106 : référence indéfinie vers « mxDestroyArray_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:108 : référence indéfinie vers « matClose_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:116 : référence indéfinie vers « matOpen_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:125 : référence indéfinie vers « matGetVariable_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:130 : référence indéfinie vers « mxGetNumberOfDimensions_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:135 : référence indéfinie vers « matGetVariable_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:140 : référence indéfinie vers « mxIsFromGlobalWS_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:145 : référence indéfinie vers « matGetVariable_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:151 : référence indéfinie vers « mxGetString_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:162 : référence indéfinie vers « mxDestroyArray_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:163 : référence indéfinie vers « mxDestroyArray_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:164 : référence indéfinie vers « mxDestroyArray_800 »
/usr/bin/ld : /home/baptiste/Code_Info/PLPLP4/PLPLP4_DEV/essai/Debug/../matcreat.cpp:166 : référence indéfinie vers « matClose_800 »
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné le statut de sortie 1
make: *** [makefile:60 : essai] Erreur 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

So I try following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61220237/undefined-references-for-mat-h-in-c to put
-l/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so -l/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so in poperties >> C++ Build >>Settings >>GCC C++ Linker >> Linker flags.

I get

```
19:00:44 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project essai ****
make all 
Building target: essai
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -l/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so -l/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so -o "essai" ./matcreat.o   
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -l/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -l/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné le statut de sortie 1
make: *** [makefile:60 : essai] Erreur 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete
```

Any Idea?
I am new in C++, thanks in advance
B

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the instructions how you are supposed to run `ldd` in the build process. According to your output, the command `ldd -d  libmat.so` is not executed but inserted as a string into the compile command, effectively adding command line arguments `ldd`, `-d`  and `libmat.so` which are interpreted as input files or options for `g++`.

Answer (score 0):

`ldd` is not a command for compiler. It is a tool which gives you list of dynamic libraries which are needed by some executable (or another dynamic library).

Remove it from compiler's command line.

First you compile the source code into object file (key `-c` in compiler's command line). The result would be in file matcreat.o (key `-o "matcreat.o"`).

That file (and probably some other) would be linked to build the executable or dynamic library (that command is not in your post - cannot tell anything about it).

`ldd -d /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so` gives you a list of libraries used by the dynamic library `libmat.so`, without all of them the library itself will not work.

If you successfully compile and link your own executable (or library) against libmat.so, then `ldd myexe` will show the `libmat.so` (but not the libraries used by libmat.so).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are fully right, ldd shoudn't be inserted into the compiler command. I made this mistake yesterday really late in the night. So my question become clearer. When I compile, the compiler cannot find functions which are located in libmat.so.

Comment: Is it possible to delete my post, it would be better to start a new topic? Or should I post my new error message?

Comment: I edited the question instead. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally succeed with the following settings
[image]

Unfortunately I cannot run the exe file since it do not find the libraries.

This will be another topic

Thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe you could summarize the contents of the screenshot, highlighting the key items you had to set?

Comment: Yes: you have to add the libraries mat, icudata, mwboost_atomic, m, mex, mx and the corresponding paths in the linker settings. The weird point is you don't have to write "libmat.so" but only "mat". Finally I can build an exe but the exe cannot find the libraies and I still don't know how top solve it